# How to re-factor a jquery function to pass selector and element id into function as parameters

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I've got jquery function that controls which checkboxes within a form are selected based upon the div element that they reside in. 
 var selectedObj = true; //located at document.ready()

```
$('#selectAllEntities').click(function (event) {
    if (selectedObj == true) {
        $('#selectAllEntities').text('Unselect All');
        $(':checkbox', '#myentities').each(function () {
            this.checked = true;
        });
        selectedObj = false;
    }
    else {
        $('#selectAllEntities').text('Select All');
        $(':checkbox', '#myentities').each(function () {
            this.checked = false;
        });
        selectedObj = true;
    }
});
```

The selector and the div element (#myentities) are the only two elements in the function that will change I would really like to factor this out so I can reuse this function vs. re-writing it each time .

Where I am stuck is passing the selector as a parameter. I can't use the class as a selector due to the css inheritance of styl

```
<div id="myentities" class="rm_RoleColumn">
                <p>
                    Select the entities that this role can view</p>
                <a id="selectAllEntities" class="am_Button floatLeft">Select All</a>
                <hr class="hrNoColor" />
                <div>
                    <asp:Panel ID="pnl_EntityList" runat="server" />
                </div>
            </div>
```

The panel is where the checkboxes appear. I am generating them server side and rendering them to a web control.

I've been staring at this too long so any suggestions on how to refactor this function or another way to look at this would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check this out. I just added class and used individual function and pass 2 parameter for button id and input class. To loop trough couple object you need to use class so you don't need to bring those class to your css files and just use them as target value. This way you can invoke this any time you want. http://jsfiddle.net/hz4nN/1/

Answer (score 0):

Use `.on` or `.bind` and the data parameter.

```
$(myelelement).on("myevent",{someselector: "#foobar",someid:587},function (e) {
    alert(e.data.someid);
});
```